# How can I get the application List on IPhone platform?

Tags: iphone, list

In fact there exists an other same question:"Is there a way to get a list of all classes in an iPhone application? ", but there doesn't has the answer, I need the question. I want to know how can I get the application list Info through the Iphone API.
    If can, can I start the application through the app Id like that:

```
- (IBAction)buyButton1Click:(id)sender {
        NSSet *productList = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"TAP001", @"TAP002", nil];

        SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productList];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with the current version of the iOS SDK. You can test for the existence of any installed application however like so (if they have a custom url handler):

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"cydia://"]])
{
    /* cydia installed */
}
```

You can do that with any installed application with a registered url handler.